# Why is Docker image is not appearing on Docker Hub after being pushed from Travis CI

Tags: docker, github, docker-compose, travis-ci

I tried to push my docker images from Travis CI to docker hub but its not appearing on my docker hub. All builds were successful

```
sudo: required
language: generic
services: 
    - docker

before_install:
    - docker build -t nedstark/docker-tcwlmd -f restful/Dockerfile.dev .

# script:
#     - docker run nedstark/docker-tcwlmd coverage run -m unittest discover restful/

after_success:
    - docker build -t nedstark/server ./restful
    - docker build -t nedstark/worker ./worker
    - docker build -t nedstark/nginx ./nginx
    #Log in to docker Cli
    - echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "DOCKER_ID" --password-stdin
    #Take these images and push them to docker hub
    - docker push nedstark/tcwl-server
    - docker push nedstark/tcwl-worker
    - docker push nedstark/tcwl-nginx
```

Comment: Did you manage to get the image pushed on the Hub?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create an **Access-Token** via the Docker Hub Settings --> Security
2. Add `DOCKER_USERNAME` and `DOCKER_PASSWORD` into your Travis-CI Build settings as environment variables. Make sure the `DOCKER_PASSWORD` is the generated **Access-Token** from step 1
3. in the `.travis.yml` add:

   ```
   docker login -u "$DOCKER_USERNAME" -p "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" docker.io
   ```

This should be able to trigger a build and push the Docker Image to the Docker Hub.

Answer (score 0):

faced a similar issue, Travis was showing login and push to docker as successful. but when I went to [dockerhub](http://hub.docker.com) it wasn't showing the pushed repos.

the reason was I did not verify my email address for docker hub after verification, all the pushed repos appeared on the hub.